# calling data from worksheet to the userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform, worksheet

so i have a ComboBox(ComboBox1) and from this ComboBox I would put a SO#(SalesOrder#) and click on an update button, when i click on this, the following fields would fill up according to the SO#(SalesOrder#) : TextBox1, ComboBox2, TextBox2, TextBox8, ComboBox5, TextBox4, TextBox5, ComboBox3, ComboBox4, ComboBox6, and TextBox7.

The Data needed are on the worksheet: Orders Database
The Data for SO#(SalesOrder#) is on column A and are arranged according to the input above.

I don't have a sample code yet since i still have no idea on how to do this

so basically, i want to fill up the Other Fields according to the SO# field(ComboBox1) and use it as a searchbox for my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asign a value to a text box

```
Dim OrderNumber as Range 

    Set OrderNumber = ActiveSheet.[A1]

    Me.MyTextbox = OrderNumber 'define a range inside VBA code
    ' or
    Me.MyTextbox = ActiveSheet.[A1] ' use absolute cell addressing
    ' or
    Me.MyTextbox = Range("MyWSRange").Cells(1,1) 'use a range defined in worksheet
```

With a ComboBox basically you can do the same. If you want to include the displayed value into the ComboBox DownDown list as well, you need to add it as an item

```
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.[A1]
```

Comment: but i don't want it as a absolute data on the field. I want to use the  SalesOrder# as a searchfield for my Database. thanks for the help.

Comment: then you develop a find function taking SalesOrder# as argument and returning a range with the relevant data on the sheet ... from there you proceed as per above.